# Need help to Creat a custom success and fail pages after updating mySQL via php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, updating

How do I change my script so that a successful update will automatically take me to a web page and an error will take me to a fail web page?

I would like to have two different web pages representing success or failure.

Thank you for your help.

Erik

```
<?PHP
session_start();
?>

<?php

$type=$_POST['type'];
$part_no=$_POST['part_no'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$count=$_POST['count'];
$min=$_POST['min'];
$max=$_POST['max'];

$db="naturan8_hero";

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXXXX", "XXXXXX");
if (! $link)
die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db , $link)
or die("Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error());
mysql_query(" UPDATE cartons_current SET type='$type' , description='$description' ,
count='$count' , min='$min' , max='$max' WHERE part_no='$part_no'");
echo "Record Updated";
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Please don't accept user input straight into SQL. This is enables an SQL injection attack vector.

Answer (score 0):

simple as ABC - replace

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE cartons_current ...");
echo "Record Updated";
```

with:

```
if(mysql_query("UPDATE cartons_current ...") && (@mysql_affected_rows() > 0)) {
    header('Location: success.htm');
}else{
    header('Location: fail.htm');
}
```

[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)
(...) For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

[mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) - Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query

Comment: Am i adding it to the bottom or replacing something?

Comment: use the absolute url for header location not a relative one.

Comment: Do i still need   mysql_close($link);

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query(" UPDATE cartons_current SET type='$type' , description='$description',count='$count' , min='$min' , max='$max' WHERE part_no='$part_no'");

if($query) {
  header('Location: success.htm');
}else{
  header('Location: fail.htm');
}
```

Comment: Do i still need mysql_close($link);